# Dynamic variable names with ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, dynamic-variables

I have a bunch of ssh keys in key=value form in a Hashicorp Vault which i have setup Ansible to be able to address.

I am trying to setup some new users with the keys i have stored, and failing. Basic info (username, group etc) is in a list of dicts i have created, called linux_users.

Here is how i grab the whole secret:

```yaml
- name: set the required secret as fact
  set_fact:
    secret: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=/secret/data/Exploit/PAM url={{ vault_url }} token={{ vault_token.token.auth.client_token }}') }}"
  no_log: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

I then use the vars lookup to try and get the ssh keys i want:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars', 'secret.data.' + item.name) }}"
  loop: "{{ linux_users }}"
```

The result is Ansible tells me the variable doesn't exist:

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: No variable found with this name: secret.data.pamlogon

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/test/pamuser.yml': line 19, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


  - debug:
    ^ here
```

Yet if i debug the var by its name i get the correct answer:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "secret.data.pamlogon": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAA...[abridged for security purposes]"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is just named `secret`; `secret.data.pamlogon` is another way to access fields of that variable in Jinja and is (mostly) equivalent to `secret['data']['pamlogon']`. You do not need the `vars` lookup here at all, since you are using a single static variable name. Just use the normal accessor syntax:

```yaml
  msg: "{{ secret.data[item.name] }}"
```

or

```yaml
  msg: "{{ secret['data'][item.name] }}"
```

Comment: That worked ! Thanks a lot. No idea why i got obsessed with using a lookup plugin :/